# Why does typescript allow me to override an empty state object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, state

I read this code as defining state to be empty, but when I write this code, nothing errors.

```
export default class extends Component<Props, {}> {
  state = {
    foo: "bar"
  };
}
```

This doesn't error either:

```
export default class extends Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({ foo: "bar" });
  }
```

I'm clearly not understanding something about TypeScript here. If I add an argument to the state object that is passed, both error showing the state discrepancy. It seems like `{}` doesn't provide any guard against being overwritten. I want to ensure from a linting perspective that state is always typed and pass as an argument or as null in the extension of the React Component, how can I set that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took some digging to figure out the main question as I see it: why does TypeScript allow you to assign an object with properties to a property declared as an empty object?

The answer seems to be buried in the [TypeScript spec a bit](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3111-apparent-members)

> In effect, a type's apparent members make it a subtype of the 'Object' or 'Function' interface unless the type defines members that are incompatible with those of the 'Object' or 'Function' interface.

That is to say, `{}` is treated the same as `Object` for type purposes. This allows you to create an object with additional properties of type `{}` which is what you are doing. Note that `this.state.foo` should *not* be allowed since the property `foo` doesn't exist on `{}`. Similarly, you wouldn't be able to do `this.state.foo =`.

As for why you can pass an object with unknown properties to `Object` or `setState`, that has to do with TypeScript's type compatibility. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html for one explanation

> Notice that our object actually has more properties than this, but the compiler only checks that *at least* the ones required are present and match the types required.

This also explains:

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo *excess property checking* when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments.

So the answer to your question seems to be that where you're using `{}` here, TypeScript is treating it as if you're using `Object` which is *not* an object literal type.

I'm not sure how you would enforce the state having no properties, but on the other hand, I'm not sure how that would be useful. If you want a component with no properties, use a stateless or function component.

Comment: This is great, if you want to enforce no state I guess really the answer is that you should be using a function. But if you want to you can do `Foo extends Component<Props, null>`. I'd just love some sort of linter error that tells you if you don't define state you should refactor to a function or define it explicitly. The whole implicit overloading seems like an anti pattern to me.

Comment: See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html -- TypeScript made some decisions here, largely for compatibility with JavaScript. It's not implicit overloading, it's actually *explicit* excess property checking.